# Driving the sound card in Linux

Tags: linux, audio

On a basic embedded systems speaker with a single line of output, wiggling the output as 0 or 1 in a for given periods produces sound.

I'd like to do something similar on a modern Linux desktop.  A brief look-see of Portaudio, OpenAL, and ALSA suggests to me that most people do things at a considerable higher level. That's ok, but not what I'm looking for.

(I've never worked with sounds on Linux before, so *if* a tutorial exists, I'd love to see it).

Comment: And your question is....? :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it... kinda is. While you can generate the *waveform* yourself, you still need to use an API to queue it and send it to the audio hardware; there no longer even *exists* a sane way to twiddle the audio line directly. Plus you get cross-platform compatibility for free.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] embedded systems speaker with a single line of output, wiggling the output as 0 or 1 in a for given periods produces sound.

Sounds a lot like the old PC speaker. You might still find code for it in the Linux kernel.

> I'd like to do something similar on a modern Linux desktop.

Then you need AFAIK a driver for [ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page). There you can find infos on [how to write an ALSA driver](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/ALSA_Driver_Documentation). Use PWM to produce the sound.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are many different sound cards and audio interfaces produced by different companies, there is no uniform way to have a low level access to them. With most sound I/O APIs what you need to do is to generate the [PCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) data and send that to the driver. That's pretty much the lowest level you can go.

But PCM data is very similar to the 0-1 approach you describe. It's just that you have the in-between options too. 0-1 is 1-bit audio. 8-, 16-, 24-bit audio is what you'll find on a modern sound card. There are also 32- and 64-bit float formats. But they're still similar.